# Basic JavaScript program

Tags: javascript

I want to Visible the combo Box named Cities when i click the Country Pakistan.. but the combo box visibility remains Hidden.. how do i do so ? I think my Code is correct but it is not working :s .. Help Required..

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>           
    <select id="Items" name="Countries">
        <option id="Pakistan" onClick="VisibileTrue()">Pakistan</option>
        <option id="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
    </select>        
    <select id="Items2" name="Cities" style="display:none">        
        <option>Karachi</option>
        <option>Sindh</option>        
    </select>
</div>
</form>
</body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">    
    function VisibileTrue() {    
        var element = document.getElementById(Pakistan);
        if(element == Pakistan)
        {
            var element2 = document.getElementsByTagName("Items2");
            element2.style.display = "inline";
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this acceptable?:

```
   1 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="stackoverflow.aspx.cs"
   2     Inherits="aspnetdiprova.stackoverflow" %>
   3 
   4 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   5 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   6 <head runat="server">
   7     <title></title>
   8 
   9     <script type="text/javascript">
  10         function VisibileTrue() {
  11             var element = document.getElementById("Countries");
  12             if (element.value == "Pakistan") {
  13                 var element2 = document.getElementById("Items2"); 
  14                 element2.style.display = "inline";
  15             }
  16          }
  17     </script>
  18 
  19 </head>
  20 <body>
  21     <form id="form1" runat="server">
  22     <div>
  23         <select id="Items" name="Countries" onchange="VisibileTrue()">
  24             <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
  25             <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
  26         </select>
  27         <select id="Items2" name="Cities" style="display: none">
  28             <option>Karachi</option>
  29             <option>Sindh</option>
  30         </select>
  31     </div>
  32     </form>
  33 </body>
  34 </html>
  35
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but it was too late for me :).. i did the same thing and was happily working :).. thank you walter

Answer (score 1):

this is javascript question.
you should use the onchange event on the select.

```
<select id="Items" name = "Countries" onchange="check(this)">
</select>


function check(elem) {
    alert (elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].innerHTML)
}
```

Comment: i wanted to do such that when i select the country from the combo box, the city combo box visible to true and corresponding cities against the selected country are shown in the city combo box..

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said already, you need to use the `onchange` event of the drop down list itself, the `option` tag has no events of its own.

You also have to add `value` to each option in order to identify the selected value, and remove the meaningless `id` from each option.

Your HTML should look like this:

```
<select id="Items" name = "Countries" onchange="CountryChanged(this);">
    <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
</select>
```

And the required JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function CountryChanged(oDDL) {
    var blnPakistan = (oDDL.value.toLowerCase() == "pakistan");
    var oCityDDL = oDDL.form.elements["Cities"];
    if (oCityDDL)
        oCityDDL.style.display = blnPakistan ? "" : "none";
}
</script>
```

This will show the `Cities` drop down when Pakistan is selected and hide it back when other value is being selected.